# Installing jQuery plugin, undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-joyride

I am trying to install a jQuery plugin: [Joyride](http://zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin).

I have included the javascript files as the documentation says, they are invoked. From the Chrome Debugger, I see `$.fn.joyride` being defined. But in the `$(window).load` method, `$.fn.joyride` returns undefined.

Any ideas? Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/underscore.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/modernizr.mq.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery.joyride-2.1.js"></script>

$(window).load(function() {
    $('#chooseID').joyride({
        autoStart : true,
        modal:true,
        expose: true
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any other errors in the console?

Comment: Nope. No other errors.

Comment: Could you post the whole code to JSFiddle please?

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it. Was including it twice! (facepalm)